# New Azure Active Directory app which a user did not create is listed in account

Tags: sharepoint-online

My company uses Office 365 and SharePoint online for all of our work.  I was just looking around in our Azure account and noticed a new app registered under Active Directory -> App Registration titled `SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal` that was created on 2/13/2019.  It has a client secret and exposes this API `https://microsoft.spfx3rdparty.com/user_impersonation`.  I didn't create this and am the only person internally who would has accessed account.  Is this some kind of default app that Microsoft may have added to my account?  Is there a way I can turn it off without deleting it, to see if it breaks anythings?  And if so turn back on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal  is default App created that is required for SPFx sign in. I think it would have been created when you deploy first SPfx solution on your SharePoint online.

You should not delete it, it will break you SPfx solution. there are threads around this on what happens when it is deleted accidentally.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2473
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2522

One of comment from

*I guess that the "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal" is supposed to handle SPFx signins and therefor needs permissions to Sign in users from AAD granted globally and that this one lacks the grant that was previously globally deployed from Microsoft.*

To restore you have to use powershell with below command(https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2522#issuecomment-422296053)

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADDeletedApplication
Restore-AzureADDeletedApplication -ObjectId <your_object_id>
```

So do not delete it if you need SPFx solutions to work.

Hope this helps...Happy coding..!!

Comment: I figured this might be a default app, but given that I'm the only one who's touched the site I thought it was best to confirm rather than assume.  Thanks!